# Border of single th spreads to neighboring th when colspan set on td row below

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table

Having following html code:

```
<table>
<tr><th>First</th><th class='second'>Second</th><th class='third'>Third</th><th>Fourth</th></tr>
<tr><td>Mike</td><td colspan=2 >John</td><td>Paul</td></tr>
</table>​
```

And following css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
border: 1px black solid;
}

td {
    border-top: none;
}
th {
    border-bottom: none;
}
th.second {
    border-bottom: 3px green solid;
}
th.third {
}
```

​
I would expect as result one table with 3px solid green line below the second th cell.
Instead of that in Chrome, I have solid green border below both the second and the third th cell.

In the firefox, results are just as expected. Is this browser bug, or my code is illegal?

You can see example at http://jsfiddle.net/tt6aP/3/

PS: Try to set

```
th.third {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

And then try to raise it to 3px. This is even more strange.

**Screenshots**

Expected:
[image: Table as seen in firefox]

Chrome:
[image: Table as seen in chrome]

Firefox:
[image: Table as seen in firefox]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Also, could you reword your question to make it more clear what you see and what you expect to see?

Comment: I have added screenshots

Comment: Are you only looking at this in the fiddle? Put your code into a static HTML file and load it into Chrome, do you see the same thing? I don't. I see the correct display in Chrome and the incorrect display in the fiddle in Chrome.

Comment: @mmcglynn You need to add `table{border-collapse: collapse;}` rule

Comment: Cool! Glad you found your answer.

Comment: @mmcglynn Not really. This does not explain different behaviour in firefox and chrome. I am still interested if it is ilegal to set the border of only one th when colspan and border-collapse are in use, or it is just chrome bug.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if it's a bug or not, but when I ran across this 
problem, I came up with a simple workaround: insert an extra row/column 
where you want to apply border styles.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Ano</th>
        <th class='first'>First</th>
        <th class='second'>Second</th>
        <th class='third'>Third</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='hack'>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mike</td>
        <td colspan=2 >John</td>
        <td>Paul</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr.hack > td {
    height:0px;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px black solid;
}
tr.hack > td, td {
    border-top: none;
}
tr.hack > td, th {
    border-bottom: none;
}
th.first {
    border-bottom: 3px green solid;
}
th.second {
}
th.third {
}
```

I tested this on chrome [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/DHr98/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Another example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/huggz/LVjja/3/

A little easier to follow, I think.  My solution was pretty easy.  I didn't need `border-collapse: collapse` set.  Changed my table to:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

and everything worked just fine.  I have to think that's a bug though.  Feels like Chrome is just choosing the wrong border length to display, when it collapses the borders.  It's displaying the length for the row above rather than the length for the current cell.

Another solution would be to add a 0 width column before the bordered cell, like so http://jsfiddle.net/huggz/LVjja/6/

css:

```
.hack {
    width: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">3 Cols</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hack"></td>
    <td class="top_border">1 details</td>
    <td>2 normal</td>
    <td>3 normal</td>
</tr>
```